# Update column with procedure output

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as shown below -

```
           Table1
   Col1     Col2    Col3
    1         a     NULL
    2         b     NULL
    3         c     NULL
```

I have a procedure usp_calculateResult(Col1,Col2).

Now what I want is to update Col3 with the the output of procedure usp_calculateResult. 
For example, if I want to update Col3 with value of Col1, then we would execute: UPDATE Table1 SET Col3=Col1.
I need to replace Col1 with a procedure output.

I am using SQL Server 2005. Please help.

Note : usp_calculateResult has two input parameter and one output parameter. I can't post the procedure due to security issue.

[EDITED : ADDED]

As per the below discussion, I think I have to make a function same as the procedure. I don't see any other options. Can anyone please comment on this?

Comment: Do you really need to execute your sp for every row?. It sounds that you could use a computed column instead. Can't you obfuscate your sp and tell us what it does?, that way we can work out a set based solution for this

Comment: Instead of using an `output` parameter that you then have to save back to `Col3` in the table, why can't the stored procedure just set the value for `Col3`?

Comment: If you redefined your SP as a function you could call it like `UPDATE Table1 SET Col3 = usp_calculateResult(Col1,Col2)`, but I agree that might become too expensive

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs. In my actual environment, this procedure is used within few other procedures. So I can't really modify it. Also the query within it is too complex. So I can't really do like update Table1 set cast(Col3 = cast(Col1 as varchar(10)) + Col2 as varchar(30)) where Col3 is null.

Answer (score 0):

Given from your context that your proc returns only one value, you should reformulate your proc as a user defined function. You should then use this to create a calculated / computed column as here (the simple formula given in the example can be directly replaced by your function) info here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx and here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

This approach will work in 2005, 2008, 2012.

Comment: We can't really make comuted column. Any option other than making comupted column or converting procedure to function.

Comment: Seems like you dont have access to the original code then? In which case the answer is no. If this is not the case, then extract the code, creat a udl and wherever the code is used, replace it with the udf and test. Its what testing against a development copy is for.